# Autohotkey replace alt and lbutton with control lbutton?

Tags: drag-and-drop, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

How to replace in autohotkey **ALT** + **LBUTTON** with **CTRL** + **LBUTTON**?

What I want is to copy selected text (drag and drop) when is pressed ALT + LBUTTON and dragging (like we do in Windows when using CTRL + LBUTTON and drag selected text)

Here is code which work when we release shortcut but also we have to one more time click on selected text and then drag it.

> !LButton:: 
>       Lalt::Control

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution that I came up with:

```
!LButton::
    Send {Ctrl Down}{LButton Down}
    dragging := 1
    return

~*LButton::
    if dragging
        Send {Ctrl Up}{LButton Up}
    dragging := 0
    return
```

I tried using GetKeyState() of the mouse button at first, but I didn't find it to be reliable.

It's also worth noting that !LButton does not behave as the Ctrl modifier does.  They must be pressed at the same time, not Alt then LButton.

Comment: I made a small change.  Try it one more time.  You should be able to highlight text, press Alt+LeftMouse and drag.  Then once you click left mouse again, it will drop the text onto where you are pointing.

Comment: thnx man but still don't work it show "+" but when I click lbutton someone else (after dragging) it want copy selected item

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

```
    ;CoordMode, Mouse, Screen

~!LButton::
    ;MouseGetPos, begin_x, begin_y
    while GetKeyState("LButton")
    {
        ;MouseGetPos, x, y
        Send {ctrl down}
        ;ToolTip, % begin_x ", " begin_y "`n" Abs(begin_x-x) " x " Abs(begin_y-y)
        Sleep, 10
    }
    ;ToolTip
Send {Ctrl up}
return
```